# How to publish application update on Android market?

Tags: android

I have to publish first update for my publish application. I want to do it right, but have no idea how :( Any help please?

Comment: You'll need to sign your app with the same certificate as the first version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest.xml, increment the versionCode (e.g. from 1 to 2), and optional, increase the versionName.

Then just create the signed .apk exactly as before (same key) and upload it to the Market.

**Edit**
In the developer console, select your application and go to the apk files tab. When your in 'simple' mode, you can indeed just upload the file and be done. When in advanced mode, you can upload the file, turn off the old apk, and turn on the new .apk file.

And, as @Eamorr said, don't forget to save ofcourse :)

Comment: And just upload it, no need to remove / unpublish old version?

Comment: Don't forget to hit the "Save" button!